# Change terminal labels of phylogram - plotBS function {phangorn package}

Tags: r

I want to change terminal/taxa colour to blue, for specific taxa.

I'd like to change "Pomquet Lake", "Lake Ainslie", "Black River", "Pinchgut Lake", and "Blue Pond" to blue. is there a way to do this?

Code (figure below):

```
datos <- read.csv("median_pairwise_fst_symmetrical_matrix.csv", header = T)
datos
    Antigonish Landing  Porper Pond Pomquet Lake    Lake Ainslie    Black River Humber Arm  Cooks Brook Pinchgut Lake   Blue Pond
Antigonish Landing  0   0.025582025 0.02402512  0.05318788  0.048140935 0.024418855 0.03129783  0.02347399  0.07519133
Porper Pond 0.025582025 0   0.015812685 0.04788476  0.041689325 0.02314917  0.025054945 0.01994431  0.07265985
Pomquet Lake    0.02402512  0.015812685 0   0.04857848  0.04012056  0.021178595 0.022014615 0.01181791  0.07245041
Lake Ainslie    0.05318788  0.04788476  0.04857848  0   0.02110537  0.05151381  0.053934035 0.049447515 0.082419055
Black River 0.048140935 0.041689325 0.04012056  0.02110537  0   0.048189365 0.04667099  0.04325165  0.078212705
Humber Arm  0.024418855 0.02314917  0.021178595 0.05151381  0.048189365 0   0.02447251  0.02178926  0.07327166
Cooks Brook 0.03129783  0.025054945 0.022014615 0.053934035 0.04667099  0.02447251  0   0.025337775 0.07057093
Pinchgut Lake   0.02347399  0.01994431  0.01181791  0.049447515 0.04325165  0.02178926  0.025337775 0   0.071362675
Blue Pond   0.07519133  0.07265985  0.07245041  0.082419055 0.078212705 0.07327166  0.07057093  0.071362675 0

#initiate cols with all black
cols <- rep('black', nrow(datos))

#turn red the specified rows and columns with freshwater populations
cols[row.names(datos) %in% freshwater_pops] <- 'blue'
cols[colnames(hmap) %in% freshwater_pops] <- 'blue'

rownombre <- datos[,1]
rownames(datos) <- rownombre
fst.matrix_mine <- datos[,-1]
fst.matrix_mine <- as.matrix(fst.matrix_mine)
    
    
###################For a UPGMA tree:##########################
require(stats)
tree_UPGMA <- ape::as.phylo(stats::hclust(stats::dist(fst.matrix_mine), method = "average"))
bootstrap.value <- ape::boot.phylo(phy = tree_UPGMA, 
                  x = fst.matrix_mine, FUN = function(xx) ape::as.phylo(stats::hclust(stats::dist(xx), 
                  method = "average")) , block = 1, B = 10000, trees = FALSE, rooted = TRUE) 

bootstrap.value <- round((bootstrap.value/10000)*100, 0)
bootstrap.value
tree_UPGMA$node.label <- bootstrap.value

plotBS(midpoint(tree_UPGMA),p = 10, type="phylogram", main= "UPGMA Phylogram - All SNPs")
```

[image]

Comment: Showing the data is one step forward, but needs still manual work to help you. Please make a dump, and include the result:

`dump(datos)`

Comment: I get: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid first argument

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, please use `dput(datos)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No data are given, so that the example is not fully reproducible. The following general example using `hclust` may hopefully give you an idea:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=20)
row.names(x) <- LETTERS[1:20]

# first 10 red, next 10 blue
colors <- rep(c("red", "blue"), each=10)

hc <- hclust(dist(x))
plot(as.dendrogram(hc), horiz = TRUE, leaflab="none")
mtext(hc$labels, at=hc$order, side=4, line=0, col=colors, las=1)
```

[image: tree diagram with colored labels]